1) How to filter only certain cells and 2) Also keep grouped rows together when filtering?
I have a google sheet that I would like to be able to filter only certain cells of a column instead of the whole column or a range. For example, I would like to be able to alphabetically filter "Property Names" in column D. But the property names are only in certain cells. Is there a way to make a filter with only specific cells not in a range? For example: Property Names are in cells D5, D16, D28, D40, etc...
Also, How do I keep grouped rows permanently together? This is another problem I have encountered. When I use a filter or sort, that it jumbles all the grouped cells. For example: rows 5-15 are grouped but when I filter the rows do not stay together.


Welcome. Please do read [ask] and use a second question for the second part of your post.

Many ways to achieve that, depending on the result you want. Here are 2 of them.
Filter view
You can try by saving a filter view on column D

Select column D
from the menu go to Create filter view
for the filter go to Filter by condition >>Custom formula is
Use this formula =A1:A22<>""
Save the view under a name like Properties


Using a formula
In a new, empty column try this formula
=LET(xx,INDEX(IF(A5:A250<>"",D5:D250,"")),
     SORT(FILTER(xx,xx<>"")))


Hi! Thanks for your response. Your first suggestion unfortunately would not allow me to expand my collapsed rows. Is it possible to sort/filter "property names" or dates and still expand the rows they are grouped with? Your second suggestion gave me a "formula parse error".  I'm not sure if I can attach a picture in the comments to show you.

@RM Images cannot help. Please read how to create and share a test sheet or this post so as you can be further helped.
